# How to zoom into a location in google map in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

This's on map ready function. I want to zoom into that location. but using this only can get marker not zoom.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!

        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
```

Comment: The docs would probably help? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#moving_the_camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to zoom onto the user location

```
> private void showArea(LatLng latLng) {
>     CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(AppConstant.MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM).build();
>     mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
> }
```